# Removing Selection, StyledTextCtrl - wxpython

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

I am look for a function to remove selection in a StyledTextCtrl (Select nothing)

```
txt.SetSelection(-1,-1) #Seems to select everything


txt.SetSelection(-1,0) # This will select the first letter
```

Does anyone know how this can be done? I can't seem to find it in the API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
txt.SetSelection(0, 0)
```